# Get value from remote page and store as local variable

Tags: php

I have a page on a remote server that returns a single xml value

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Tracker>12345</Tracker>
```

How do I go about getting the value 12345 or whatever is in the  tag into a PHP variable?
I know I can't do something as simple as:

```
<?php
    $var = http://www.www.com/file.php;
    echo $var;   //12345
?>
```

I'm new to the entire idea of creating a web service - I think that's what this should be.?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go in two steps :

- Get the XML string from the remote server

  - with [curl](http://www.php.net/curl), for instance
  - or with [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)
- and, then, parse that XML to extract the data

  - with [`simplexml_load_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) for instance

Note that those two steps can be merged as one, using [`simplexml_load_file`](http://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file), if the configuration of your server allows you to do that.

Once you have that XML in a PHP variable, using SimpleXML, it's quite easy to get the value you want. For instance :

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><Tracker>12345</Tracker>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo (string)$xml;
```

Will get you

```
12345
```

And getting the content of that XML from the remote URL can be as simple as :

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://your-remote-url');
```

And if you can do that, you can also use that remote URL directly with SimpleXML :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://your-remote-url');
echo (string)$xml;
```

But this will only work if [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled in your server's configuration.

If `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on your server, you can get the XML from the remote server using curl ; something like this should do the trick, for instance :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://your-remote-url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$string = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And, then, you can still use `simplexml_load_string`, as I did in my first example.

*(If using curl, take a look at the documentation of [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) : there are several options that might interest your -- for instance, to specify timeouts)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP that good, but:

1. Download the contents of the XML file - read it for the remote location
2. Parse the XML
3. store the value of the parsed element in a varianble

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$var = $xml[0];
```