# How can i get a website to open up a page server side?

Tags: php, web, server-side

I want to create a callback feature. E.g. The client does something but then we need to open up a page with a few GET variables to one of our partners. Therefore id like to make a PHP script which opens a website with all the data in the URL (The user shouldnt see this, it should be done server sided). How could I do this thanks.  A bit like some IPN systems. Sorry that the question is not very well constructed if you need more detail ill provide more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from remote page and store as local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958778/get-value-from-remote-page-and-store-as-local-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `fopen` okay, though `fsockopen` is more appropriate for a remote URL, but I find [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to be much more powerful. You'll need to have compiled PHP with support for CURL, but it's a default package on many systems. You can check if your current system supports it by pulling up a `phpinfo()` page and looking for CURL.

The benefit of using CURL is you get really fine grained control over the request and how to handle the response. The php docs have [a fairly concise example of how to use CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php); due to the number of options available it can get verbose quickly. The functions you'll use most are `curl_init`, `curl_setopt` and `curl_exec`

Comment: I haven't used file_get_contents(), since fsockopen and curl are my tools of choice. It looks like it would work as well enough, particularly if you don't have access to curl.

Comment: 'file_get_contents()' will work as will 'file()' and 'fopen()'.  fopen() or (fsockopen if you must) has the advantage of not needing to read the contents - which means the user doesn't have to wait.  I call it "open and forget" or simply a "ping" (though not a true ping).

Answer (score 2):

See [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen).  If you are expecting to get a response from the other server, you can use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to read the response.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). It's a really powerful API.